# Problem: web page rendered correctly internal network and incomplete externally

Tags: html, browser, rendering, external

I have a website on the server where I work, on the internal network the website is seen correctly, (it is a grid that retrieves data from a database), the 97421 rows of the html page are rendered completely and correctly.

If I view the same website from an external network (from home, mobile phone ...etc), the web page renders up to exactly 16623 rows, both with Crome and Edge:

**CROME**
[image]

**EDGE**
[image]

INFO: From internet the site is reachable through the web application firewall installed on a SonicWall SMA500v appliance.

(in practice it renders about 1/5 of the full content) it doesn't go wrong, it simply doesn't write the whole page, I deduce that it doesn't depend on the browser but on the network depending on whether I'm inside or outside.
Do you know what could be the cause?
Thank you

Comment: Seems unlikely it will have anything to do with the visual rows, but the quantity of actual data... especially if the HTML is just cut dead in the source view.  Sounds more like an infrastructure issue than a programming one... maybe a firewall restriction?